# RVM - Do I need Ruby 1.8.7 in order to install Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I just need some clarification on a line I read after running `rvm requirements`. It says

```
To install rbx and/or Ruby 1.9 head (MRI) (eg. 1.9.2-head), then you
must install and use rvm 1.8.7 first.
```

Does this mean RVM version 1.8.7 or Ruby version 1.8.7? I'm currently running RVM version 1.10.2 with no gems installed, but I want to only install 1.9.3. Thanks!

Comment: are you on an old version of rvm?

Comment: @Nick What command are you using? You should run `rvm install 1.9.3`

Comment: @lucapette I haven't done that yet because I wanted to make sure I met all requirements as per `rvm requirements`. Though that's the command I was planning on using. Just to clarify, I'm not getting an error message, I just wanted to make sure that line referred to `rvm 1.8.7` and not `ruby 1.8.7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at [the most recent revision of that part of RVM](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/859d76f681379ae8941be95e0134f491041eec09/scripts/requirements), it seems like you get that message automatically. It's targeted at *nix users so I can't check it currently, but all such users should get that message from `rvm requirements`. It's been there since last September, and it's not a warning that you haven't met a dependency. (Note that it also says bash, curl, git and patch are required, and you likely have those, too.)

In any case, it's referring to the RVM version, which for you is two minor versions ahead. It's an understandably confusing message as 1.8.7 is also a fairly widespread version of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

This means RVM version 1.8.7, not Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: you're not an rvm user, are you?

Comment: Only intermittently. I get the same message as him, but I was able to install ruby 1.9 without ruby 1.8.7, so I'm 99% sure I'm correct on this one.